# How to start a php local server from a batch file?

Tags: php, batch-file

ok so i have been working on a dev project just for fun and i have a problem, i want to start a php -S localhost server. It's starting but on the wrong port

Here is my code :

```
@echo off
SET var=

for /f "delims=" %%i in (info.txt) do call :setVar %%i
cd %var%
php -S localhost:%var%

:SetVar
Set var=%var% %1%
goto :eof
```

And here is the txt file :

```
P:\HTML\Ch3rry-site
80
```

Helppp!

Comment: try `php -S "localhost:%var%"` adding double cotes.

Comment: It should be `%1` not `%1%`.

Comment: With that corrected, your `for /f` loop is propagating each non empty line of `info.txt` which doesn't begin with the character `;` into `%%i`. You are then `call`ing `:SetVar` and creating a new variable named `%var%`, which will, in your example look like this, `<space>P:\HTML\Ch3rry-site 80`. Now you're using it as the name of your new current directory `CD  P:\HTML\Ch3rry-site 80`. Then you're running this command, `php -S localhost: P:\HTML\Ch3rry-site 80`. Then you're pointlessly running `Set var=%var% %1` again before ending the script. Now can you see where you're going wrong?

Comment: You should also be using `CD /D` as it is likely that you're supposed to be changing to a different drive too! It is also likely, that you should be using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

like Compo said you should try cd /d if the file is in different directory  but even so here is a batch file(it needs two files,one for the port and other for the path and make sure to change the php path to your installation directory) i created that worked on my pc:

```
@echo off
set /p var=<file.txt
set /p path=<path.txt
cd /d %path%
C:\php-8.0.0-Win32-vs16-x64\php.exe -S localhost:%var%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the already provided answer, but without changing you single `info.txt` file:

```
@Echo Off
Set "FolderPath="
Set "PortNumber="
(   Set /P "FolderPath="
    Set /P "PortNumber="
) 0< "info.txt"
If Not Defined PortNumber Exit /B 2
CD /D "%FolderPath%" || Exit /B 1
php.exe -S 0.0.0.0:%PortNumber%
```

I would additionally advise, *(if `php.exe` is not located in the directory listed in the first line of `info.txt`)*, that you provide the full path to `php.exe` to prevent reliance on the easily modified, and often broken, `%Path%` variable.